# disabling 'full screen mode' in Lion (to use transparent full screen iTerm2)

Tags: osx-lion, fullscreen, iterm2

I like using my iTerm2 window in transparent mode, full screen so I can code and see my desktop picture as well.

I have upgraded to Lion and now when I enter full screen it gets rid of my desktop!

Is there any way to change this? Mission Control is fantastic, but this single thing is bothering me a lot. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to see your desktop background, you can set iTerm2 to use a background image as well.

Answer (score 12):

It took me a while to find this tonight, so I’ll respond here since this was near my top search results for how to disable Lion fullscreen mode in iTerm2, and this is probably what many people will be looking for.

1. In iTerm2, open *Preferences*
2. Select *General*
3. Uncheck *Lion-style fullscreen windows*

Comment: here, have as many upvotes as you like fine sir.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, iTerm2 Version 3 (currently, 2.9.20160206 beta) lists this option as *Native full screen windows*, under the heading *Window*.

Comment: and be sure to uncheck "Disable transparency for fullscreen windows by default" under Preferences > Appearance > Window